# Understanding the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend, fetch-api

I understand that a website may have a front end (client) and a back end (server) and that the server makes calls to 'external' REST APIs such as woocommerce etc.

Why does one have to set up a whole structure called a backend in order to make calls to a REST API using languages such as Node (Express)? Why can't one just make calls in the front end using `fetch('https://woocommerce/products')`?

Edit: Thanks everyone for posting your answers its helped my understanding a lot! Please feel free to continue and provide any other insight and especially examples as to why your answering as such it'll help me and other future newbies who may come across the question.

Comment: Fundamental web security measures prevent what you're asking about.

Comment: In some cases you *can* do without writing any backend code, but in general your backend is doing things like: storing data that *isn't* in some external API; using credentials you *don't* want arbitrary client to have access to; or providing additional business logic to simplify your client code.

Answer (score 2):

So, in concept in newer browsers they can do so from the client, if the server has setup [cross-origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).  Lacking that, and in older browsers, requests to third parties will be blocked due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Furthermore, in many cases you don't *want* the client to make requests directly, because you will then have to expose your API keys to everyone who has access to the clientside code. Some services have ways around that (e.g. Firebase), but most do not.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not required to setup a backend. There's plenty of ways you can run the site without setting up a backend. You can use BAAS services like Firebase

But, the problem with using only client is a user can see every request the client makes. And access the data sent or the sensitive API keys sent in the request - this is really bad for security and can end up being misused.